# React Navigate Page

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-18

I am trying to navigate the page when the button is clicked.

Here is my code which does not work;

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./LoginPage.css";

class LoginPage extends Component {

  render() {
    const style = {
      margin: "15px 0",
    };
    return (
      <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={this.getAuthentication}>
          Enter
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getAuthentication() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('/staff')
  }
}
export default LoginPage;
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/staff in the browser it works fine. But when I tried to navigate with a button click it didn't work.

I am using the class component I searched the whole day and I didn't find any solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'react-router-dom' for navigation but it must be a functional component.
if you want to use class based component, you can combine them like this:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

class LoginPage extends Component { 

render() {
const { navigate } = this.props;

  return (    
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={()=>navigate('/register')}
            >
              Enter
            </button>
          </div>            
  );
}    
}

   export default function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <LoginPage navigate={navigate}/>
  );
}
```